# Telerik CellFormatting column color is not working

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, cell-formatting

I want to change color for the columns in the RadGrid Telerik. I want to give a color to the `col index 2,3` and different color the to `col Index 0,1`.

The color for col 2,3 is working but for`Col index  0,1 is not working,` there is no color in the index `Col index  0 & 1`

This is the code:

```
bool dontRunHandler;
private void datagridview_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.DrawFillProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
    e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.NumberOfColorsProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
    e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.GradientStyleProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
    e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.BackColorProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);

    if (dontRunHandler == false)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 2 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 3 ) return;
        e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
        e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;
        e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        e.CellElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Linear;


    }

    else
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 1 ) return;
        e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
        e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;
        e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
        e.CellElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Linear;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I need to clarify what you were after earlier today. I'll be in the chat room tom afternoon around 1PM CST.

Comment: KreepN : The place where i'm doing this Telerik stuff, i cant use the Chat is disabled incl SO Chat but i can access the SO web. I'll let u know, what am i up-to, this evening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that it will run only one condition out of two.
If `dontRunHandler =false` it will color cells  2 and 3.
else if `dontRunHandler =true` it will color cells 0 and 1.
 Try to remove if else, and see if it solves a problem.

now this happens because first if statement returns because it thinks that your column is not 0 or 1.

My suggestion to you is to use [ColunnCreated](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-oncolumncreated.html) event instead. Suppose to be faster and more semantic.

```
  protected void RadGrid1_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.IsBoundToFieldName("ProductID"))
        {
            e.Column.ItemStyle.CssClass = "MyClass1";
        }
        else if (e.Column.IsBoundToFieldName("ProductName"))
        {
            e.Column.ItemStyle.CssClass = "MyClass2";
        }
    }

...
    <style type="text/css">
        .MyClass1
        {
            color: Red;
        }

         .MyClass2
        {
            color: Blue;
        }
    </style>
```

Do you think this is something that will work for you. Or you are specifically using indexes for some reason?

if you want your example to work, I would do something like this:

```
 e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.DrawFillProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.NumberOfColorsProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.GradientStyleProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.BackColorProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);

        if (e.CellElement.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.CellElement.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
            e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;
            e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
            e.CellElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Linear;
        }

        else if (e.CellElement.ColumnIndex == 0 || e.CellElement.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
            e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;
            e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.MediumVioletRed;
            e.CellElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Linear;
        }
```

Comment: removed if else,still no change.